# Gnome 3 programs apparently disappearing in Arch Linux?

Tags: gnome, arch-linux, gnome3

I’m on Arch Linux using Gnome 3, and programs will randomly “disappear” after a length of time sometimes, but I know they are working in the background. For example, I had TeamSpeak up, left my computer for a while, came back and the window is gone. However, I can still hear and talk to my friends.

I’ve tried clicking windows button, they aren’t listed there. I’ve seen people say you can check the panel, but I’m not sure what they are talking about as I’m not able to right click anything on any panel I can see.

What is happening?

Comment: The Panel is the like the Windows Task Bar.  On the panel you also have Separate Desktops 1-4 typically (far right hand side).  Click those and you will get a fresh desktop1 to desktop4.  How about a screenshot?

Comment: @StackAbstraction I do see those (there are 2). But there is nothing on the 2nd one. I'm not at my computer right now so I can't get a screenshot for you, but I can when I get home.

Comment: @Austin Are you having problems with GDM 1st login?

Answer (score 3):

It is probably a gnome shell environment bug.
Read it somewhere, don't remember, that gdk-pixbuf was causing it.
Run `pacman -S gdk-pixbuf2` to solve this.

Comment: It looks like the package was already installed so it just reinstalled it. I will see if it helps. Thanks.